# Lua Roblox API: Equivilance Arithmetic Operations and Roblox API Objects: Why does one expression yield false and one yield true?

Tags: lua, roblox

**Context:**

There are two equivalence comparison expressions below. Both expressions are very similar. Both the left side and right side of all four arguments yield the same value in the output box, but the difference across the expressions (which I found) are the types of the objects being compared (as left-side and right-side arguments). So, then one expression yields a boolean value of "true" with respect to the equivalence operation and the second expression yields a boolean value of "false" with respect to the equivilance operaetion, though in both expressions, the individual output values (on the output box) are the same, and the types are the same within that expression. (I.e., each expression I am trying to yield a true value, but only one comes out as true).

**Question**

Why does one expression (with objects of type "string") yield "true" and the other expression (with objects of type "Instance") yield "false"?

**Code:**

```
--In context of these following 2 function in the following 2 lines:
    box.Touched:Connect(onTouchedDebounced)
    function onTouchedObject(otherObjectPart)

--consider the following code:


--After declaring objects to be compared below in the following 3 lines:    
     local otherObjectPartsParent=otherObjectPart.Parent;
     local resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherObjectPartsParent);

--Here I want to say:
--ActiveUserPlayerName == ActiveUserPlayerName is true
--Where: (#1): Object1 = "ActiveUserPlayerName";
--Where: (#2): Object2 = "ActiveUserPlayerName";
--Where: (#3): Left_Side_Arguement = ActiveUserPlayerName of type Instance
--Where: (#4): Right_Side_Argument = ActiveUserPlayerName of type Instance
    print ("resultsFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction: ", resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction); --OUTPUT: ActiveUserPlayerName
    print ("otherObjectPartsParent.Name: ", otherObjectPartsParent); --OUTPUT: ActiveUserPlayerName
    print ("typeof(resultsFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction): ", typeof(resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction)); --OUTPUT: Instance
    print ("typeof(otherObjectPartsParent): ", typeof(otherObjectPartsParent)); --OUTPUT: Instance
    print ("resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction == otherObjectPartsParent is: ", resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction == otherObjectPartsParent); --OUTPUT: False


--Here I want to say:
--ActiveUserPlayerName == ActiveUserPlayerName is true
--Where: (#1): Object1 = "ActiveUserPlayerName";
--Where: (#2): Object2 = "ActiveUserPlayerName";
--Where: (#3): Left_Side_Arguement = ActiveUserPlayerName of type string
--Where: (#4): Right_Side_Argument = ActiveUserPlayerName of type string
    print ("resultsFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DisplayName: ", resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DisplayName); --OUTPUT: ActiveUserPlayerName
    print ("otherObjectPartsParent.Name: ", otherObjectPartsParent.Name); --OUTPUT: ActiveUserPlayerName
    print ("typeof(resultsFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DsplayName): ", typeof(resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DsplayName)); --OUTPUT: string(*corrected)
    print ("typeof(otherObjectPartsParent.Name): ", typeof(otherObjectPartsParent.Name)); --OUTPUT: string (*corrected)
    print ("resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DisplayName == otherObjectPartsParent.Name is: ", resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DisplayName == otherObjectPartsParent.Name); --OUTPUT: True
```

Comment: The question has nothing to do with C. I've removed the tag. Two (or many) Roblox `Instance` objects can have the same `Name`. Maybe try also checking the `ClassName` of the objects?

Comment: You are comparing two reference objects as opposed to two values.  Two different objects can never be equal, simply because they aren't the same object.  strings, on the other hand, are compared as values.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure I understand the question. What about the behavior doesn't match what you would expect?

Comment: This outputs true:
print ("resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DisplayName == otherObjectPartsParent.Name is: ", resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DisplayName == otherObjectPartsParent.Name);

Comment: This Outputs false: print ("resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction == otherObjectPartsParent is: ", resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction == otherObjectPartsParent);

Comment: Even though all of these objects output ActiveUserPlayer in output box: resultsFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction otherObjectPartsParent resultsFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction.DisplayName otherObjectPartsParent.Name

Comment: I edited the code with comments for clarity.

Comment: In the first part, it's misleading to think of the values as **being** `"ActiveUserPlayerName"`. They are Roblox objects which **have** `"ActiveUserPlayerName"` as the `Name` property, but that doesn't mean they're the same Roblox object.

Comment: --Okay! That may be my mistake on how i interpret the "Output" box text. So, even if I see a "label" in the output, the actual value is represented as a reference/pointer in some sort of virtual addressing/reference system?

Comment: Thank you, Russ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable names make this *very* hard to read. But by renaming `otherObjectPartsParent` to `character` and `resultFromGetPlayerFromCharacterFunction` to `player`, it makes a lot more sense what's happening.

```
local character = otherObjectPart.Parent;
local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(character);

print ("player : ", player); --OUTPUT: ActiveUserPlayerName (a tostring'd version of the Player object)
print ("character.Name: ", character.Name); --OUTPUT: ActiveUserPlayerName
print ("typeof(player): ", typeof(player)); --OUTPUT: Instance (of class Player)
print ("typeof(character): ", typeof(character)); --OUTPUT: Instance (of class Model)
print ("player == character is: ", player == character); --OUTPUT: False (pointer comparison, these are two different objects)

print ("player.DisplayName: ", player.DisplayName); --OUTPUT: ActiveUserPlayerName
print ("character.Name: ", character.Name); --OUTPUT: ActiveUserPlayerName
print ("typeof(player.DisplayName): ", typeof(player.DisplayName)); --OUTPUT: Instance (this looks wrong, this should be a string)
print ("typeof(character.Name): ", typeof(character.Name)); --OUTPUT: Instance (this also looks wrong, this should be a string)
print ("player.DisplayName == character.Name is: ", player.DisplayName == character.Name); --OUTPUT: True (string comparison, this should be correct)
```

At the end of the day, you are comparing two different objects. When someone joins the game, their [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player) is added to the Players service, and their [Character](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/Player/Character) is added to the Workspace.

The Player and Character have the same names, but one represents who they are on Roblox and the other is their physical representation in the game.

And when it comes to comparisons, it matters what kinds of types you are comparing. Lua primitives like bools, ints, strings, and nil will compare by value. Tables and userdata objects will compare by pointer reference. So when it comes to Roblox lua, you need to pay attention to the object types you're dealing with. Instances are userdata under the hood so just because two objects have the same name, they won't always be equal.

Comment: Thank you, Kylaaa for your explanation.

Comment: For clarification, the == operation compares the value stored in an object, but the values being compared are references/pointer to two different objects of different classes despite having similar labels on the output? Its a little confusing.

Comment: Definitely, want to get better at this but hoping to get the official text for roblox-lua when it comes out ASAP--but the release date is months away! In the meanwhile, thanks so much.

Comment: Maybe, a better question to ask is this: Is there a function that could output the "class" types you mention (Character class and Player class)?

Comment: Sure, all Instances have a ClassName property which will give you a string name for a class. For inheritance checking, there's also the IsA(class name ) function on all Instances. Your code was relying on typeof() which is just a Roblox variant of lua's type() function, and that is good for identifying primitives and Instances, but that won't identify the kind of Instance.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include more details about the == operator works

Comment: Thank you Kylaaa! :)